# Equation roots: parameter doesn't get simplified

Tags: python, parameters, equation, sympy

I am using Python with Sympy.

I need to solve the following equation, finding the 4 roots (omega is my unknown):

```
deter= 0.6*omega**4*cos(omega*t)**2 - 229.0*omega**2*cos(omega*t)**2 + 5880.0*cos(omega*t)**2
```

I tried to use solve:

```
eqcarr=solve(deter,omega,exclude=[t])
```

I get this output:

```
[-18.8143990830350, -5.26165884593044, 5.26165884593044, 18.8143990830350, 1.5707963267949/t, 4.71238898038469/t]
```

I only need the first 4 values, and not the values with the t coefficient. I expect the cos(omega*t)**2 to be simplified in solve, but this doesn't happen.

Answer (score 2):

According to documentation `solve` will not solve for any of the free symbols passed in the `exclude`.

> 'exclude=[] (default)'
>      don't try to solve for any of the free symbols in exclude;
>      if expressions are given, the free symbols in them will
>      be extracted automatically.

It is not meant to filter solution.

You can solve your problem by doing this:

```
In [10]: from sympy import *
In [11]: from sympy.abc import omega, t
In [12]: deter= 0.6*omega**4*cos(omega*t)**2 - 229.0*omega**2*cos(omega*t)**2 + 5880.0*cos(omega*t)**2

In [13]: eqcarr=solve(deter,omega,exclude=[t])

In [14]: filtered = [i for i in eqcarr if not i.has(t)]
In [15]: filtered
Out[15]: [-18.8143990830350, -5.26165884593044, 5.26165884593044, 18.8143990830350]
```

Comment: This solution works but I would like to know the meaning of the solutions with the t so that I can understand how to manage them.

Comment: The ``t`` you passed in the expression is just a symbol and has no value assigned to it. So it will appear as it is in some of the solutions.

Comment: The solutions come from the fact that you can factor out a `cos(omega*t)**2` from your expression. The two solutions with `t` in them make `cos(omega*t)` equal to 0. Symbolically, they are `pi/(2*t)` and `3*pi/(2*t)`. The other four roots are the roots to the polynomial `0.6*omega**4 - 229.0*omega**2 + 5880.0`.